# Regular expression to find any number in a string

Tags: python, regex

What's the notation for any number in re?
Like if I'm searching a string for any number, positive or negative.
I've been using \d+ but that can't find 0 or -1

Comment: Try `r"-?\d+"`. EDIT: - don't need escape outside `[]`

Comment: Regex doesn't read things by what they are, but what character class they are in, so you need an optional "-" character to match negatives. That said, \d+ absolutely *should* match 0, it's in the \d character class `[0-9]`.

Comment: What about `1.0e+3` or `-123.456` - do you want to match those, too?

Comment: -1: Terrible title for the question.  Uninformative.  Not helpful to others with a similar problem.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Searching for positive, negative, and/or decimals, you could use `[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?`

```
>>> nums = re.compile(r"[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?")
>>> nums.search("0.123").group(0)
'0.123'
>>> nums.search("+0.123").group(0)
'+0.123'
>>> nums.search("123").group(0)
'123'
>>> nums.search("-123").group(0)
'-123'
>>> nums.search("1").group(0)
'1'
```

This isn't very smart about leading/trailing zeros, of course:

```
>>> nums.search("0001.20000").group(0)
'0001.20000'
```

**Edit**: Corrected the above regex to find single-digit numbers.

If you wanted to add support for exponential form, try `[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:[eE][+-]?\d+)?`:

```
>>> nums2 = re.compile(r"[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:[eE][+-]?\d+)?")
>>> nums2.search("-1.23E+45").group(0)
'-1.23E+45'
>>> nums2.search("0.1e-456").group(0)
'0.1e-456'
>>> nums2.search("1e99").group(0)
'1e99'
```

Comment: Correct me but your regex will not match single digits numbers?

Comment: Ah, good catch. I'll update it to make that post-decimal part optional.

Comment: Great answer, what's the purpose of the "()” in "[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?"? If we no need to extract the group information, can we remove it?

Comment: Nice question @Beatlej. The parens are needed because the entire group `\.\d+` is optional, i.e. all or nothing. Starting a group with  `?:` means the group is non-capturing, though, so there actually isn't a `group(1)` or `group(2)` in the results. See also http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html

Comment: This won't work for `1.` in which case it only returns `1`. This may not be what you want. The corrected regexp would then be: `r"[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d*)?(?:[eE][+-]?\d+)?"`

Comment: It will not work for `.5` either, while this `r'[+-]?\d*(?:\.\d*)?(?:[eE][+-]?\d+)?%'` would do the trick

Answer (score 4):

`\d` should be fine for matching any nonnegative integer. `\d` is equivalent to `[0-9]` (any single digit character) so of course it won't match negative numbers.  Add an optional negative sign in that case:

```
\-?\d+
```

`\d` will definitely match `0`.

Answer (score 3):

To match positive or negative numbers, as in `-3` or `+5`, use `[+-]?\d+`:

```
re.findall('[+-]?\d+', 'sfkdjfsdfj-1skjfslkdjf+4')   # ['-1', '+4']
```

Make sure you put the negative sign last so the compiler understands you don't mean something else.

Answer (score 0):

\d will match 0 by default, so the only need is to modify your regex to match negative values, to do so you can simply use:

```
import re
re.findall(r'[+-]?\d+', ' 1 sd  2 s 3 sfs 0 -1')
```

OR

```
import re
re.findall(r'(?<!\S)[+-]?\d+(?!\S)', '234 +1 -10 23jjj ssf54 sdg5dfgdf') 
>>> ['234', '+1', '-10']
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [python re documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html), \d matches any digit if the UNICODE flag is not set. If the flag is set, then it matches anything considered a digit in that locale.

It won't match negative numbers without some additions though:

```
-?\d+
```

This works, but does not get any number, since numbers are quite complex little things. 
Try this one:

```
[-+]?\d*\.?\d+([eE][-+]?\d+)?
```

Answer (score 0):

Philosophically ;-), neither integer nor fractional part is mandatory. Still, at least some of those two should present. To avoid boring enumeration of regexp branches, we could rephrase the latter requirement as "some digit should occur either immediately at start (not counting an optional sign) or after a dot". We can easily express this wish in terms of look-ahead, getting the following:

```
import re
num_regex_str = r"[+-]?(?=\.?\d)\d*\.?\d*(?:[eE][+-]?\d+)?"
num_regex = re.compile(num_regex_str)
    
text = "  .6 2.6 0. -3.5 -.5 -5. -.5E-26 +.5E+26 -. +. "
list(map(float, num_regex.findall(text)))
>>> [0.6, 2.6, 0.0, -3.5, -0.5, -5.0, -5e-27, 5e+25]
```